# Java mulithreading HiLo game

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

For my CS class I have to write a HiLo game using multithreading.  I am brand new to multithreading and not sure how to best implement it.  The program below works, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.  When it is run the user will input a int which is the amount of time that they will have to guess the correct number.  If the timer runs out the game will end.  I am not supposed to use the Timer object but instead use the System.currentTimeMillis().

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Game implements Runnable {
    private static long time;
    private long timer;
    private static long gameTime;

    public Game(int n){
        gameTime=n;
    }

    public void run() {
        time=System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(true){
            timer=(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000;
            if(timer>=gameTime){
                System.out.println("Oops! Time is up - try again.");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Hilo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length!=1){
            System.err.println("Must enter time");
        }
        Random rand = new Random();
        int max=100;
        int min=1;
        int number=rand.nextInt((max-min)+1)+min;
        int gameTime=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println("Welcome to HiLo!");
        System.out.println("You have "+gameTime+" seconds to guess a number between 1 and 100.");
        Thread clock1 = new Thread(new Game(gameTime));
        clock1.start();

        while(clock1.isAlive()==true){
            System.out.println(">");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int input = sc.nextInt();

            if(clock1.isAlive()==true&&input==number){
                System.out.println("You Win!");
                break;
            }else if(clock1.isAlive()==true&&input<number){
                System.out.println("Higher!");
            }else if(clock1.isAlive()==true&&input>number){
                System.out.println("Lower!");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com. That said: `booleanExpression == true` is ugly. Just use `booleanExpression`. The `time` and `gameTime` variables should not be static. Add white spaces around operators, before parentheses, etc. to make the code readable: `if (clock1.isAlive() && input == number) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a thread that sleeps for T seconds and then exits calling System.exit().